# Missing or invalid url parameter (upload with media) API Twitter

Tags: api, twitter

Help please... I can send tweets, but when try to upload with media says "missing or invalid url parameter"

I tryed with many ways of define "media", only url, getfilecontent("url"), "@"."url", and more...

I use Abrahams library (twitteroauth)

This is my code:

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once('twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');
require_once('config.php');

if (empty($_SESSION['access_token']) || empty($_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token']) || empty($_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token_secret'])) {
    header('Location: ./clearsessions.php');
}
$access_token = $_SESSION['access_token'];

$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $rowTwitter["twitter_token"], $rowTwitter["twitter_token_secret"]);

$msg = $_POST["texto2"];
$image = $_POST["URL"];

$parameters = array(
            'media[]'  => "{$image}",
            'status'   => "{$msg}"
        );

$code = $connection->post('statuses/update_with_media', $parameters);  

var_dump($code);

?>
```

And this is the result:

object(stdClass)#5 (1) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#6 (2) { ["code"]=> int(195) ["message"]=> string(33) "Missing or invalid url parameter." } } }

EDITED: Hi again! I added this code:

```
$filename = $image;
$handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
$image = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
```

And now this is the problem:

object(stdClass)#5 (1) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#6 (2) { ["code"]=> int(189) ["message"]=> string(22) "Error creating status." } } }

Answer (score 0):

i did it using modified library

---html---

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
      <label for="status">Tweet Text</label>
      <textarea type="text" name="status" rows="5" cols="60"></textarea>
      <br />

      <label for="image">Photo</label>
      <input type="file" name="image" />
      <br />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
  </form>
```

---php---

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
      // we set the type and filename are set here as well
      $params = array(
        'media[]' => "@{$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']};type={$_FILES['image']['type']};filename={$_FILES['image']['name']}",
        'status'  => $_POST['status']
      );

      $dd = $twitteroauth->post('statuses/update_with_media',$params,true);

      var_dump($dd);
}
```

download modified library here

https://github.com/tomi-heiskanen/twitteroauth/blob/77795ff40e4ec914bab4604e7063fa70a27077d4/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php